# Counting distinct values related to distinct values within another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am using SQL to look at repeat custom. Through a few different views I have got to a point where I have, simplistically, a set of file numbers (duplicated for several values in one field), enquiry numbers attached to each file no, and some other info.

I can get around counting distinct values of File Numbers by using a data model in excel. What I do want and cannot get is a count of distinct enquiry number against a distinct file number - there can be the same enquiry number against several file numbers. Data example as below (real data is far more lengthy):

```
Enquiry Number    File Number
1              a
1              b

2              c
2              c
2              c

3              d
3              e
3              f
3              f
```

If I do a distinct count in excel as with the file numbers, I will only get 4, whereas I want it to show 6 (2 distinct values for file number 1, 1 for 2 and 3 for 3). Spent many hours and three people on this so any help would be very much appreciated.

output wanted as below. "company" is how I will group these in excel (there are about 15 other fields that I don't want to add for sensitivity/time reasons):
    Company    File Count    Enquiry Count
    A          2             2
    B          4             1
    C          3             3

Comment: how should the output look like?

Comment: What I am looking for is something like the below (or I think in comments itll be headings, row 1, row 2, row 3 values):

    Company,        File Count,         Enquiry Count,
    A                     5                       3,
    B                     4                       2,
    C                     7                       4,

Comment: please add it to the question. where is company coming from?

Comment: company is just how I am grouping these values in excel. This is attached to file number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CONCAT to combine those two values and then count the distinct combinations:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(file_number, enquiry_number))
FROM t
```

Comment: this looks promising - ill give it a go!

Comment: doesnt seem to work... but I've tried taking the count and distinct out and using a distinct count on these in excel and getting somewhere so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for in SQL.

```
   SELECT [File Number], COUNT(DISTINCT[Enquiry Number]) as Count
   FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment but I've tried this and it will give me a lower number than I am looking for. This will give distinct enquiry values from the column, not as a subset as it were of file number. this may be in the confusing nature of my question so apologies